# php mysql while loop slideshow

Tags: javascript, php, loops, while-loop

my code is

```
<div align="center">
    <div id="imgGallary" class="container">
    <?php $get_products = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM products"); while ($show_products = $get_products->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <h1><?php echo $show_products['name']; ?></h1>
            <img src="img/<?php echo $show_products['img']; ?>" alt="" width="100%" height="300" >
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function(){
            var imgLen = document.getElementById('imgGallary');
            var images = imgLen.getElementsByTagName('img');
            var counter = 1;

            if(counter <= images.length){
                setInterval(function(){
                    images[0].src = images[counter].src;
                    console.log(images[counter].src);
                    counter++;

                    if(counter === images.length){
                        counter = 1;
                    }
                },2000);
            }
    })();
</script>

.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px #00274F solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

everything is ok and images working perfect but i cant display others row
like name

```
<h1><?php echo $show_products['name']; ?></h1>
```

first item name display and not change just first item name and images ok change

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work. Right now, there aren't any `<?php echo $show_products['name']; ?>`.

Comment: <div align="center">
<div id="imgGallary" class="container">
<?php $get_products = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM products"); while ($show_products = $get_products->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
  <h1><?php echo $show_products['name']; ?></h1>
  <img src="img/<?php echo $show_products['img']; ?>" alt="" width="100%" height="300" >
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Also, look at the rendered html source and check if the names are outputted correctly (if it's your HTML/CSS/JS that needs to be changed)

Comment: yes updated my question . i want to slideshow 3 rows for every item . it slideshow just for images and others 2 rows not

Comment: Since your slide show only changes the actual images and not anything else, there's no wonder why you won't see the other names. I would rethink the slider layout/javascript. Put each slide in a div and change the the div instead.